# select query to get value from a table of an interval

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with these values...

```
id colA     colB      colC  
55 00:00:00 NULL      NULL  
56 01:01:02  0.00007   0.00007
57 02:01:02  0         0.00007
58 03:01:02  0.00006   0     
59 15:01:02  0.00012   0.00006
60 16:01:02 -0.00008   0.00012
61 20:59:02 -0.00006  -0.00008
62 21:05:01  0.00005  -0.00006
63 22:01:02 -0.00013   0.00005
64 23:01:02  0.00004  -0.00013
65 00:00:01 -0.00012   0.00004
66 01:01:02 -0.00004  -0.00012
67 02:01:02  0.00006  -0.00004
68 03:01:02  0.00004   0.00006
69 15:01:02 -0.00004   0.00004
70 16:01:02  0        -0.00004
71 23:01:02 -0.00014   0      
72 00:00:01 -0.00011  -0.00014
73 01:01:02 -0.00004  -0.00011
74 02:01:02  0.00011  -0.00004
75 03:01:02  0.00005   0.00011
76 15:01:02  0         0.00005
77 16:01:02 -0.00008   0      
78 23:01:02  0        -0.00008
79 00:00:01  0.00003   0      
80 01:01:02 -0.00009   0.00003
81 02:01:02 -0.00007   0      
82 03:01:02 -0.00007  -0.00016
83 15:01:02  0.00044  -0.00007
84 16:01:02  0         0.00044
```

Now I want to get the SUM of colb, colc on each time colA value changes to 15:01...
The output should be like the following

```
colA            sum(colB)       SUM(colC)
 15:01:01.582   0.0002500   0.0002000
 15:01:01.582   -0.0002800  -0.0001200
 15:01:01.582   -0.0001300  -0.0001700
 15:01:01.582   0.0001600   -0.0002800
```

Can anyone please help me with this query.

Comment: Can you please be more precise in what you mean by "each interval between". This could be interpreted a number of ways. Perhaps you can provide the expected output in a table?

Comment: @Turophile...the SUM(colb) on everytime colA value changes to 18:01, but it should be started from the last 16:01

Comment: I have not used any PRIMARY KEY here

Comment: @Turophile...please see I have added the desired output

Comment: I don't understand how you produce that result set from that data set. Maybe switch to something smaller/simpler?

Comment: @Strawberry...well am explaining it...see the first 15:01:02 at id 59...the sum of colB at this point is .00025 and sum of colc is .00020 then again at id 69 the colA becomes 15:01 so the sum of colB (id 60 to id 69) is -.00028...hope am clear to you...please let me know for any further clarification

Comment: Again, clarifications need to be incorporated as edits to the question. I understand the first one. It's all the others that I cannot figure out!!

Comment: @Strawberry...the second time colA value becomes 15:01 then the colB values from id60 to 69 is added...then third time 15:01 occurs then colB values from id 70 to 76 is added...and so on...it would be really helpfull if I could share this whole data structure in an excel

Comment: @Strawberry...now does it make any sense?am really clueless how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

You can characterize each row by the number of `cola` values that are `18:01` that appear after it.  Then you can group by this number.

In MySQL, the easiest way to get this number is by using variables:

```
select grp, max(cola), sum(colb), sum(colc)
from (select t.*,
             (@grp := @grp + (cola = '18:01')) as grp
      from table t cross join (select @grp := 0) vars
      order by id desc
     ) t
group by grp;
```

Comment: @Strawberry...I have edited my post...I am not sure whether its precised or not...sorry again dear